# Not Able to fetch Title in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image: Source Code]

I am trying to fetch title from the source code.
I have written multiple xpaths but i am getting an

**Error :** DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead

```
enter code here
try:
    #title = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1/img').text.strip()
    #title = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='cp-typography--hero-title-logo']/img").text
    #title = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "content-page__programmatic-header").text.strip()
    print("Title: "+title)
except:
    print("Missing Title")
```

help me with this

Comment: you are trying to fetch page title or what

Comment: I'm trying to fetch title.

Comment: You can use driver.title for this. in your case browser.title. As I can see in your xpaths you are targeting h1 tag that doesn't have any inner text, so .text will not return anything,

Comment: @vineetsingh - I took variable name __ browser = webdriver.Edge('msedgedriver.exe')
browser.maximize_window()